# php form post array order

Tags: php, arrays

In php, if you name your form fields using numerical indexes, they work as arrays in the $_POST object.

```
<form method="post" action="post.php">
    <input type="text" name="question[0][name]" />
    <input type="text" name="question[0][email]"/>
    <input type="text" name="question[0][password]" />
    <hr>
    <input type="text" name="question[1][name]" />
    <input type="text" name="question[1][email]"/>
    <input type="text" name="question[1][password]" />
    <hr>
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    <hr>
    <p><?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    echo json_encode($_POST, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}

     ?></p>
</form>
```

outputs

```
{"question":[{"name":"a","email":"aa","password":"aaa"},{"name":"b","email":"bb","password":"bbb"}]}
```

If the ordering of the fields is not sequential starting at zero and incrementing by only one each time the name is repeated, then they are all interpreted as keys instead. So

```
<form method="post" action="post.php">
    <input type="text" name="question[1][name]" />
    <input type="text" name="question[1][email]"/>
    <input type="text" name="question[1][password]" />
    <hr>
    <input type="text" name="question[0][name]" />
    <input type="text" name="question[0][email]"/>
    <input type="text" name="question[0][password]" />
    <hr>
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    <hr>
    <p><?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    echo json_encode($_POST, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}

     ?></p>
</form>
```

outputs

```
{"question":{"1":{"name":"a","email":"aa","password":"aaa"},"0":{"name":"b","email":"bb","password":"bbb"}}}
```

Is there a way to get $_POST to ignore the order of arrays of post keys so they are interpreted as an array?

Comment: Another way is to sort $_POST array when get.

Comment: @ShivaniPatel your example of this?

Answer (score 1):

Please check if helpful or not :

```
<form method="post" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="question[1][name]" />
    <input type="text" name="question[1][email]"/>
    <input type="text" name="question[1][password]" />
    <hr>
    <input type="text" name="question[0][name]" />
    <input type="text" name="question[0][email]"/>
    <input type="text" name="question[0][password]" />
    <hr>
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    <hr>
    <p>
 <?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {                     
            ksort($_POST['question']);          
            print_r($_POST['question']);
    }

 ?>
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: It will sort array according to keys.

Comment: In my first code, it doesn't matter what the field names are. In the "fix", the field names have to be known ahead of time. Is there a way to sort all field names in the POST object without necessarily knowing their names ?

Comment: Please check this helpful or not, i have implement function like this :http://i.imgur.com/8yfZN0f.png and output is http://i.imgur.com/7SiRiaR.png